# Hibernate criteria generates query that involves table that is not mentioned anywhere

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have this access to database:

```
 public List<Farm> getUserFarms(int userId) {
    
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();  
    
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Farm> query = builder.createQuery(Farm.class);
    Root<Farm> variableRoot = query.from(Farm.class);
    Join<Farm, Account> joinObject = variableRoot.join("account", JoinType.INNER);
    Join<Account, User> joinObject2 = joinObject.join("user", JoinType.INNER);
    
    Predicate restriction = builder.and(
            builder.equal( variableRoot.get("Id"), userId)
    );
    
    query.select(variableRoot).where(restriction);
    

    List<Farm> farms = session.createQuery(query).getResultList();

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();

return farms;
}
```

And generated SQL is like this:

Hibernate:
select
accounts0_.User_id as User_id1_3_0_,
accounts0_.accounts_id as accounts2_3_0_,
account1_.id as id1_0_1_,
account1_.balance as balance2_0_1_,
account1_.number as number3_0_1_,
account1_1_.User_id as User_id1_3_1_,
farm2_.id as id1_1_2_,
farm2_.account_id as account_2_1_2_,
farm2_.name as name3_1_2_
from
users_accounts accounts0_
inner join
accounts account1_
on accounts0_.accounts_id=account1_.id
left outer join
users_accounts account1_1_
on account1_.id=account1_1_.accounts_id
left outer join
**customers** farm2_
on account1_.id=farm2_.account_id
where
accounts0_.User_id=?

As you can see table *customers* appears in query even I didn't mentioned it anywhere.

And in List I got customer instead of farms.

Any comments or help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Entity model:

Account

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="id")
private int Id;

@Column(name="balance")
private double balance;

@Column(name="number")
private String number;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "users_accounts", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "accounts_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "User_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private User user;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Farm farm;
```

and getters and setters in every class.

Farm:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Farm implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int Id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @OneToOne
    private Account account;
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int Id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;
    
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
    
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
```

And Customer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int Id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;
    
    
    private int account_id;
```

Comment: We would need to at least see the entity model to help you. Also, are you using the latest Hibernate version 5.4.30? If so, and you still have the problem, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I added entity model. Yes I'm using Hibernate 5.4.30.

Comment: `Farm` uses the same table `@Table(name = "customers")` which is why you see the `customers` table in the SQL.